# Liferay Bundle or WAR installation?

Tags: windows-server-2003

I am about to install Liferay for our organization. We have do not have an enterprise Java platform or Tomcat server so I was thinking of installing the bundle.
However, once I run the bundle and logoff, Tomcat is killed. What is the best practice for this? Should I download the WAR and manually install Tomcat server with the WAR or is there a way to have the Bundle run without having to have a user logged in to the Windows Server?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do one of two things. Personally I use the bundles for a dev/test environment and then build out a correct tomcat application environment and deploy the war file. However, with the bundle there should be a way to create a service within that bundle so that it can handle a user logoff. http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Starting+Liferay+as+a+Windows+Service

Comment: Do you think there is an issue with running the bundle as a service?

Comment: No not necessarily. If you are not comfortable doing the build out then the bundle is the way to go.